# ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access. on AWS RDS MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

> ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access

I am getting above error while executing this command

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://com.price.images/devops/price_final_mmvy_01162024.csv'
INTO TABLE price_2024
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS 
(city_id,variant_id,year,month,km,fairdealer,gooddealer,excellentdealer,fair_max_quote_price,fair_min_quote_price,good_min_quote_price,excellent_min_quote_price,excellent_max_quote_price,quote_price,quote_increased_by,state_id,min_quote_price,max_quote_price,good_max_quote_price,very_good_min_quote_price,very_good_max_quote_price,status);
```

on AWS RDS MySQL Using jump-server.

Please help on this

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;


LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://com.price.images/devops/price_final_mmvy_01162024.csv'
INTO TABLE price_2024
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS 
(city_id,variant_id,year,month,km,fairdealer,gooddealer,excellentdealer,fair_max_quote_price,fair_min_quote_price,good_min_quote_price,excellent_min_quote_price,excellent_max_quote_price,quote_price,quote_increased_by,state_id,min_quote_price,max_quote_price,good_max_quote_price,very_good_min_quote_price,very_good_max_quote_price,status);
```

> ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

This above error getting while executing the above command and it is for AWS RDS MySQL

Comment: You cannot perform `SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;` because you are not Amason RDS administrator. You cannot set it for your connection because this variable have only global scope.

Comment: How Can I resolve this any solutions

Comment: [Loading data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading_data.html) - study. You'd use COPY command.